# Why can't IntelliJ find org.gradle.api libs, when OSX CLI can?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

IntelliJ IDEA v2019.2

I have a Gradle plugin project that builds on my OSX command line via `./gradlew build` for example. I’ve “Import from existing source” the project into IntelliJ and when I build, I get

```
Error:(3, 22) java: package org.gradle.api does not exist
Error:(4, 28) java: package org.gradle.api.tasks does not exist
Error:(5, 36) java: package org.gradle.api.tasks.options does not exist
Error:(6, 22) java: package org.gradle.api does not exist
```

and of course because of this I get subsequent Cannot fine symbol errors. This in my build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
  id 'idea'
  id 'java'
  id 'maven'
  id 'maven-publish'
  id 'java-gradle-plugin'
}
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin'

group=project.groupId
version = '0.0.1'

dependencies {
  compile gradleApi()
}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'artifactId': project.artifactId,
               'groupId': project.groupId,
               'version': project.version
  }
  baseName artifactId
  doLast {
    println "artifactId: $project.artifactId\ngroupId: $project.groupId\nversion: $version"
  }
}


jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'artifactId': project.artifactId,
               'groupId': project.groupId,
               'version': project.version
  }
  baseName artifactId
  doLast {
    println "artifactId: $project.artifactId\ngroupId: $project.groupId\nversion: $version"
  }
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        simplePlugin {
            id = 'com.zift.utilities.zift-version-plugin'
            implementationClass = 'com.zift.utilities.ZiftVersionPlugin'
        }
    }
}
```

I see `org.gradle.api.*` in the project's External Libraries list.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

If I open the Gradle sidebar and double-click `Tasks->build->build` it builds, but when I click the green hammer to `Build Project` it fails there. What's the difference? (I'm new to IntelliJ).

Comment: Did you import it as a Gradle project? If so, try refreshing it through the "Reimport all Gradle Projects" icon in the Gradle sidebar.

Comment: Thanks @BjørnVester. I just did this to no avail. I did `Refresh Gradle Dependencies` and `Reimport Gradle Project`

Comment: What is IDE version? Show you Gradle settings in IDE. What does `compile gradleApi()` do?

Comment: You need to set Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | 'Build and run using' to **Gradle**. Then IDE will use Gradle itself to build and run the project.

Comment: @Andrey, thanks, but I already have it set up this way. I updated OP to give IDE version.